# How to install gtsummary?

Tags: r, rstudio, gtsummary

I am using Windows. R and R studio are both in working order. But I'm not able to install gtsummary, it keep  saying in the console as attached pic, please advise, thanks very much
Regards,
Amanda(student)

[image]

I have downloaded rtools in hope of resolve the problems, but somehow the rtools did not show in the r studio despite that I have definitely installed it

Comment: You could install all the packages and say that you want the packages to be compiled from source. Often, this solves R package installation problems. Also, you are using which version of RTools?

Comment: Rtools is not actually installed through R, you have to click here and install it like any other software. There is no package called "RTools". https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/files/rtools43-5550-5548.exe

Comment: you might want to go through a tutorial, that could be of some help to you, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2IPWVXaUuU